# Tiled 2d maps guidelines

Tags: android, andengine

I am using Tiled to create a Tiled map for a project.

I just cant get the tiled map to show up directly on the screen. The map is always displayed off the screen.

Is there a guideline for creating these 2d based tiled maps to work on all devices?

Comment: Something like the Google I/O application?

Comment: Well its a Game project..It has a Tiled map llike this..http://www.mapeditor.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can find nice 2D tutorials [here](http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series-part-i,770.html).
You can also have a look at [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/), which is a nice wrapping for 2D.

Comment: Im actually using andengine. it works very good. The only problem i am having is with the Tiled maps using in AndEngine. I just cant get mine to be centered in the Screen. So i was wondering was there any guidelines for creating these for android